# Core Plot Selecting (Random) Points Challenge

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, graph, core-plot

I have made a simple graph using Core Plot in Swift (Thank You Eric!) and have the following result.

[image]

**Challenge:**

What I would like to do is get the coordinates of the tap of the user within the plot area. So if the user Taps on the point `10,20` I should be able to get that retuned. Also if the user taps the point `14,20`, 14 is not on the xAxis therefore it should get the nearest value which is 10, and would also return point `10,20`. (This should work on both axes and the values returned should be the nearest ones appearing on the axes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plot area delegate and implement one or more of the following delegate methods:

```
-(void)plotAreaWasSelected:(CPTPlotArea *)plotArea withEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
-(void)plotAreaTouchDown:(CPTPlotArea *)plotArea withEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
-(void)plotAreaTouchUp:(CPTPlotArea *)plotArea withEvent:(CPTNativeEvent *)event;
```

Use the `-plotPointForEvent:` plot space method to get the data coordinates of the interaction point from the event.

Comment: Thank you! How is it possible to implement it in Swift?

Comment: The same way you would do it in Objective-C. The method signatures are directly translatable, e.g., `func plotAreaWasSelected(plotArea: CPTPlotArea!, withEvent: UIEvent!)`.

Comment: How do I do the plot area delegate part?

Comment: Adopt the `CPTPlotAreaDelegate` protocol in whichever class will be the delegate (often the view controller) and implement the delegate methods you need. When setting up the graph, set the plot area delegate, e.g., `graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.delegate = self`.

Comment: I got it working, thank you! How do I get the Plot Space to use in the argument of `plotPointForEvent` in  `var x = CPTPlotSpace.plotPointForEvent(<#CPTPlotSpace#>)`

Comment: The plot space is the first parameter of the delegate and the event is the second.

Comment: `var x = CPTPlotSpace.plotPointForEvent(plotArea)` I get: `'CPTPlotArea' is not convertible to 'CPTPlotSpace'`

Comment: `-plotPointForEvent:` is not a class method. Try `var x = plotArea.plotPointForEvent(event)`.

Comment: I get: `'CPTPlotArea' does not have a member named 'plotPointForEvent'`

Comment: Sorry, that's a plot *space* method, not a plot area method.

Comment: `graph.defaultPlotSpace.plotPointForEvent(event)`

Comment: It worked. I got a point but not the one corresponding to my axisLabels. I clicked the point `40,20` and got `[0.5080, 0.18082524]`. 1) I will do the part where I get the nearest label happily manually, I just wanted to know if there's a better way. 2) What if I wanted to get the points as I drag on the screen?

Comment: Without know what solution you came up with, I can't help. Open a new question showing the code and describing the problem in detail.